# Centripetal acceleration for a polyline

Tags: acceleration, velocity, centripetal-force

This question is also posted on the [Mathematics forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115619/centripetal-acceleration-for-a-polyline).

I am not physicist, therefore sorry if my question is a bit primitive.

Given a polyline (x and y coordinates) in Cartesian coordinate system, how can I estimate centripetal acceleration (let's say an average one)? Each pair $<x,y>$ was measured at 1 minute interval. I know that it is the rate of change of tangential velocity. But the problem is that tangential velocity formula involves the radius of circular path, and my path (polyline) just has some curvatures. So, I don't know how to get the radius.

Any clarification is highly appreciated.

Update:
Example of a polyline -

[image]

Comment: Do you think there's a way to figure out the radius if you know the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the polyline?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to estimate centripetal acceleration from my data. Beside x and y, I have a time component. I just want to get some generic guidelines (if my task can be solved) and some links as examples.

Comment: @BMS: From trigonometry, I know that we can get angle using this formula: angle = atan2(y, x). But I don't have any idea about further steps.

Comment: Mathematics might now be a better home for your question since it's been reduced to using your pairs of coordinates to determine the radius.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos but, how do you want to calculate force is there is no indication of some time dependence? Maybe a first point was done a year ago, a second point immediately, a third point after 6 months, etc. How to calculate an acceleration?

Comment: It wasn't a good deed to simply delete this, it should have been migrated into the math SE.

Comment: @Sofia: I have a list of <x,y> pairs. Each pair <x,y> was measured at 1 minute interval. So, from this information, I can easily estimate speed and acceleration.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos : I introduced this information in your question.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos : yes, BMS is right, you have first to do a fit: you have to find two data, the origin and radius of the circle which passes closest to your points, e.g. defining as $\Delta _j$ the distance between your point $(x_j, y_j$ and the closest point on the circle, you have to minimize $\sum (\Delta _j)^2$. Once having the origin an radius, the life will become simpler.

Comment: @Sofia: Do you mean something similar to this approach?: http://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/152405

Comment: @KlausosKlausos : the idea in the reference is indeed to **fit** a circle to a set of points, but you need the utility. I don't see in the reference the utility. This is why, in parallel with applying to our site, you maybe search for a utility that can get as an input your points, and output the center and radius of the circle. However, are you sure that your points fit to one single circle? If not, you may get something wild.

Comment: @Sofia: I added an example of a polyline. I guess these points do not fit to a single circle... that's the issue. I am using R to process data,so once I understand the procedure I will search for helpful packages.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos indeed they don't. The conclusion is that it's not only a centripetal force that acts on your object, or, from some reason the centripetal force is not constant. Why do you need a centripetal force? What is the problem behind your question?